# Why is ps -u command not working?

Tags: process, ps, top, jobs

When I use the 'top' command I get

```
10366 mithus    25   0 11120 1044  884 R 99.9  0.0  67:14.35 gm
```

when I start a process using `nohup ./gm &`.

showing that a process 'gm' is running. However, when I use `ps -u @mithus` I get the following. I don't get any information about the status of the process `gm`.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mithus   13756  0.0  0.0  66076  1740 pts/1    Ss   18:29   0:00 -bash
mithus   17929  0.0  0.0  65604  1004 pts/1    R+   19:05   0:00 ps -u
```

Why `ps -u $USER` not giving the status of `gm`?

Comment: Is this `gm` program in another session where, after you nohupped it, you logged out?

Answer (score 0):

It seems odd because the default behaviour of top is to show EUSER and the the -u (lowercase) option in ps is to select based on EUID.

So we have either some difference between user and UID, some selection difference between top and ps or there is something odd about the gm process. It's interesting your process has 99% cpu and a priority of 25.

Does ps actually find this process?

> ps -ax -o pid,user,uid,cmd | grep mithus

This will find all processes, output the pid,username, user id and command and then use grep as the filter. Perhaps you have two users of the same name. Also find the PID for your gm process and try

> ps 10366

assuming it is still process 10366